# oci_execute returning wrong value for count(*)

Tags: php, oracle

I am attempting to count the number of rows that contain specific data.  In this case, I am using bind variables to perform the task.

```
<?php

$aid = 1;
$shortName = "TroubleMgt";
$description = "Trouble Management";
$type = "TroubleMgt";

# Lets assume I have already successfully connected to my database
$stid = oci_parse($cnx,"select count(*) TOTAL from aradmin.activities where aid = :aid and shortName = :shortName and description = :description and type = :type");

oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':aid', $aid);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':shortName', $shortName);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':description', $description);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':type', $type);

oci_execute($stid);

$total = oci_fetch_assoc($stid)['TOTAL'];

print $total."\n";
?>
```

That prints 4 (wrong)

The interesting part is when I do it in Oracle in the same database in the same table I get 1 as expected (there is only 1 row that should match).

```
SQL> var aid number
SQL> var shortName varchar2(254)
SQL> var description varchar2(4000)
SQL> var type varchar2(254)
SQL> begin
  2  select 1,'TroubleMgt','Trouble Management','TroubleMgt' into :aid,:shortName,:description,:type from dual;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select count(*) TOTAL from aradmin.activities where aid = :aid and shortName = :shortName and description = :description and type = :type;

     TOTAL
----------
         1
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, query look like equal, parmeters too. Then 1 see only two posibilities 1) your php scritp connect to different database 2) there is some inserts before `select count(*)` in script. Try to lock table then you may check point 2. Try to rename table and you may check point 1

Answer (score -1):

The delete commands had not been committed in the sqlplus window.  Live and learn.